# fs.watch via Node 0.5.9 on Mac OSX

Tags: node.js, kqueue

I'm running the following on Node v0.5.9:

```
var fs = require("fs");
fs.watch("/Users/username/testingFsWatcher/",function(event,file) {
  console.dir(arguments);
});
```

I then do:

- `cd /Users/username/testingFsWatcher/`
- `>file1` --> `{ '0': 'rename', '1': null }`
- `mkdir new_folder` --> `{ '0': 'rename', '1': null }`
- `>new_folder/file2` --> no event triggered/output
- `touch file1` --> no event triggered/output
- `rm file1` --> `{ '0': 'rename', '1': null }`

Two things I noticed that seem incorrect: subdirectories (`new_folder`) are not watched and updates/modifications to watched files do not trigger a `change` event. Looking over the node code and tests it seems like these should be possible.

So, is it possible to get `fs.watch` to watch a directory and all of it's subdirectories? Is it at least possible to get an event from a file modification? Also, from what I can tell, `fs.watch` is backed by `kqueue` which is tied to an `eventid` (in OSX), is it possible to get that `eventid`?

Note: I'm specifically using `fs.watch` and not `fs.watchFile` because I need to watch an entire directory (preferably all of it's subdirectories too :).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 0.5.9 is not stable. Feel free to add a bug in github with a more detail example. You could use "Supervisor" by Isaac

Comment: This issue is reported at https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1986, and is at least partially fixed under the stable 0.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the link Trevor! I'll try to post my results to that thread once I get a chance to upgrade to 0.6.0... :)

Comment: Use this instead: https://npmjs.org/package/node-watch

Answer (score 0):

This problem no longer appears in the latest Node release. However, there are several other remaining bugs in `fs.watch`, so you may want to hold off on using it until those are addressed: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/search?q=fs.watch